# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count():

Tags: php

I have a page with 2 nested loops which fail with:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, null given

I have created a test page using the offending loops:

```php
<?php

$prop_info=array();

$propRates=array();

$propRates[0]=  
    array(
    'title'=>'Test Cottage',
    'thirty_night_min' => 0,
    'id' => 1426225,
    'date_new' => 05-22
    );
$propRates[1]=  
    array(
    'title'=>'Maunawai Hale',
    'thirty_night_min' => 0,
    'id' => 1591525,
    'date_new' => 05-24
    );  
$propRates[2]=  
    array(
    'title' => 'Pines 4050',
    'thirty_night_min' => 0,
    'id' => 1503333,
    'date_new' => '05-24'
    );  
    

$prop_info[1]=$propRates;

echo('<pre>');

print_r($prop_info);

echo('</pre>');

// Offending loops
for($b=1;$b=(count($prop_info[$b])+1);$b++){
    
    for($i=0;$i<count($prop_info[$b]);$i++){
        
        echo('b: '.$b.' i '.$i.' Title: '.$prop_info[$b][$i]['title'].' ID: '.$prop_info[$b][$i]['id'].'<br />');
        
    }

}

?>
```

I've tried using `is_countable` function, but am not sure how to integrate it in these for loops.

Comment: $prop_info has only item [1] set. But the first for tries to count item [2] the second time round and it doesn’t exist. Incidentally do you mean = there or ==?

Comment: Is there a good reason anyone should be intentionally using a `for` loop? Let alone two, nested loops!

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach loops for array's. The for loop in your example has a condition mistake!

```
// Offending loops
for($b=1;$b=(count($prop_info[$b])+1);$b++){
    
    for($i=0;$i<count($prop_info[$b]);$i++){
        
        echo('b: '.$b.' i '.$i.' Title: '.$prop_info[$b][$i]['title'].' ID: '.$prop_info[$b][$i]['id'].'<br />');
        
    }

}
```

Should be:

```
// Offending loops
for($b = 0 ; $b < count($prop_info) ; $b++){
    
    for($i = 0 ;$i < count($prop_info[$b]) ; $i++){
        
        echo('b: '.$b.' i '.$i.' Title: '.$prop_info[$b][$i]['title'].' ID: '.$prop_info[$b][$i]['id'].'<br />');
        
    }

}
```

With foreach:

```
// Offending loops
foreach($prop_info as $key => $info) {
                
    echo('b: '.$key.' Title: '.$info['title'].' ID: '.$info['id'].'<br />');
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My fix was create 2 new new variables:

```
$pinfoCount=count($prop_info);
$pRatesCount=count($prop_info[1]);

for($b=1;$b<=$pinfoCount;$b++){ 
    
    for($i=0;$i<count($prop_info[$b]);$i++){
        
        echo('b: '.$b.' i '.$i.' Title: '.$prop_info[$b][$i]['title'].' ID: '.$prop_info[$b][$i]['id'].'<br />');
        
    }

}
```

and use these counts in the for loops.

This solves the:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value)
```

but not my bad logic and sloppy coding. That will just take time and experience.